# Why is there a nested class in this implementation of the HashTable ADT (code from a textbook)?

Tags: java, hashtable

I was reading my textbook and stumbled onto this piece of code:

```
 public abstract class AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size() == 0; } 
          //---------------- nested MapEntry class ---------------
              protected static class MapEntry<K,V> implements Entry<K,V> { 
                 private K k; // key 
                  private V v; // value 
                 public MapEntry(K key, V value) { 
                    k = key; 
                    v = value; 
                  } 
                 // public methods of the Entry interface 
                  public K getKey() { return k; } 
                  public V getValue() { return v; } 
                // utilities not exposed as part of the Entry interface                    
                    protected void setKey(K key) { k = key; }  
                    protected V setValue(V value) { 
                     V old = v; 
                     v = value; 
                     return old; 
                    } 
               } 
         //----------- end of nested MapEntry class ----------
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. I just can't seem to realize why is that nested class so important. Wouldn't be possible to just omit that nested class and just put all those methods in the AbstractMap class? Is it for security purposes ( like linked lists and Nodes?)

Feel free to tell me if this isn't the right place to post this question as the code isn't mine, but one from my textbook.

Comment: getKey() and getValue() return the key/value of one of the entries of the map. Putting those methods in the map wouldn't make sense: a Map has typically more than one entry.

Comment: It's a way to hide the implementation of `Entry<K,V>` from other classes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the methods you need to implement when implementing a `Map` is

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet();
```

As it has a return type of `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` you need to provide an implementation of `Entry<K,V>` for your `Map`. It is common practice to implement `Entry` as an inner class of `Map` it is an `Entry` for.

Given that an `Entry` can be used independently of the `Map` that underlies it you need to have those methods on the `Entry` class.

Comment: If EntrySet only returns an iterable collection of keys, why would it return both the key and value?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "EntrySet only returns an iterable collection of keys". It doesn't it returns a set of entries where and Entry is the pair of both key and value.